# Firebase storage error - is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using `html/JS`, I am trying to write a file.

I included this on `html` head :

```
 <head>
          <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
          <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Then at the end of the `body` I have :

```
//...
  <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>

     <script>
              var config = {
                apiKey: "xxx",
                authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "xxxx",
                storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
              };
              firebase.initializeApp(config);
              const db = firebase.firestore();
              db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true});
         </script>
```

Then on the `main.js` file when I try to write to storgae :

```
   var storageRef = firebase.storage().storage.ref()('me/' + file.name);
           var task=storageRef.put(file);
            task.on('state_changed',
                    function progress(snapshot){console.log(snapshot.bytesTransferred)},
                    function error(err){},
                    function complete(){});
```

I get this error on the console :

```
firebase.storage is not a function
```

**EDIT:**

```
Tried again and got same error with :

        // Create a root reference
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        // Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
        var finalRef = storageRef.child('me/' + file.name);  


                  finalRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot){
                      console.log('uploading');
                  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add this also:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

to be able to use firebase storage api.

Also change this:

```
   var storageRef = firebase.storage().storage.ref()('me/' + file.name);
```

Into this:

```
   var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('me/' + file.name);
```

Check this for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference

Comment: thanks fixed it - didn't help, same error when upload.

Comment: I also read the doc, and edit my question to try again, and still same error. Do I have to import something to the file main.js ?

Comment: you need to add this also `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>`

Comment: Yea! that saved me. Maybe you should add this to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change you script main.js position  like this

```
         <script>
                  var config = {
                    apiKey: "xxx",
                    authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
                    databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
                    projectId: "xxxx",
                    storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com",
                    messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
                  };
                  firebase.initializeApp(config);
                  const db = firebase.firestore();
                  db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true});
             </script>


     //to here
     <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your firebase import is correct. It won't work if you imported it incorrectly.

**It should be like this**

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Not this

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
```